# Hapi Lab - how do I have shared state between lab experiments

Tags: hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

So I made up the user domain
and I've done I think a good suite
test it's like this:

```
var Code = require('code');
var Lab = require('lab');
var lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
var server = require('../../');
var Jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var Nconf = require('nconf');
var apiConfig =  Nconf.get('api');

lab.experiment('Users', function () {

    var userId, payload, decoded, token;

    lab.test('create joi required', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/users',
            payload: {
                lastname: 'Bedini',
                username: 'whisher',
                email: 'me@ilwebdifabio.it',
                password: 'mysecret'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(422);
            Code.expect(result.message).to.equal('child "firstname" fails because ["firstname" is required]');
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('create', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/users',
            payload: {
                firstname: 'Fabio',
                lastname: 'Bedini',
                username: 'whisher',
                email: 'me@ilwebdifabio.it',
                password: 'mysecret'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {

            token = response.result.token;
            payload = options.payload;
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(201);
            try {
                decoded = Jwt.verify(token, apiConfig.secret);
            }
            catch(err) {
            }
            console.log(decoded.scope);
            Code.expect(decoded.username).to.equal(payload.username);
            Code.expect(decoded.scope).to.be.an.array();
            userId = decoded.jti;
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('create sequelize unique', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/users',
            payload: {
                firstname: 'Fabio',
                lastname: 'Bedini',
                username: 'whisher',
                email: 'me@ilwebdifabio.it',
                password: 'mysecret'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            Code.expect(result.message).to.equal('username must be unique');
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(422);
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('update at least one required', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(422);
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('update no password', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId,
            payload: {
                password: 'mysecret_update'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(422);
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('update not owner', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId +1,
            payload: {
                firstname: 'Fabio_update'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(403);
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('update', function (done) {

        var updatevalue = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
        var options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId,
            payload: {
                firstname: 'Fabio_'+updatevalue,
                lastname: 'Bedini_'+updatevalue,
                username: 'whisher_'+updatevalue,
                email: 'me_'+updatevalue+'@ilwebdifabio.it'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            Code.expect(result).to.equal(1);
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('findById not owner', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId +1,
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(403);
            done();
        });

    });

     lab.test('findById', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            Code.expect(result).to.be.instanceof(Object);
            Code.expect(Object.keys(result)).to.have.length(8);
            done();
        });

    });

    lab.test('destroy not owner', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId+1
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(403);
            done();
        });

    });

     lab.test('destroy', function (done) {

        var options = {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/users/'+userId
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            Code.expect(result).to.equal(1);
            done();
        });

    });

});
```

now I made up the product domain as well and there
is some routes needed  access token.

How can I test the product domain using the 'globals'

> var userId, payload, decoded, token;

or what's the way to turn in this case ?

### Update

after @Matt Harrison answer

```
var getToken = function(){
    var user = {id:1,username:'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'};
    var token = JwtUtil.getUserToken(user).token;
    return token;
}
lab.experiment('Product', function () {



    lab.test('create', function (done) {
        var token = getToken();
        console.log(token);
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
             headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
            url: '/api/products',
            payload: {
                title: 'myproduct'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, function(response) {
            var result = response.result;
            console.log(result);
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
           // Code.expect(result.message).to.equal('child "firstname" fails because ["firstname" is required]');
            done();
        });

    });


});
```

it workish  I've an other problem
with

> CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users`
>   (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) stack: Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I have understood your question correctly but I think you're asking:

> How do I have shared state between lab experiments?

The simple answer is to move `var userId, payload, decoded, token;` into the upper "global" scope so they can be accessed everywhere.

However my advice is **don't do this**. Your test cases should be independent from each other. You should be able to add tests, reorder them and remove them without it affecting other test cases. Otherwise you're creating a maintenance nightmare for yourself.

If you need a resource in multiple test cases, just create a new one for each test:

```
lab.test('test the thing', function (done) {

    var token = getToken();
    expect(token).to.equal(...);
});

lab.test('test the other thing', function (done) {

    var token = getToken();
    expect(token).to.equal(...);
});
```

If you need to change a resource and then test something, that's a single test case:

```
lab.test('change something and then test it', function (done) {

    var token = getToken();
    token.prop = 'value';
    expect(token.prop).to.equal('value');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the point and the clue for the title :).I think the hard thing is to set up getToken() and share it between test. Could you give me an example ? BTW in my package.json I've got "test": "lab -c ./test/e2e", what the order of loading files ? Should I do like myroottest with all the 'global' and an other mysubroottest with all the tests ?

Comment: I've updated my post any idea on how to work out the CONSTRAINT issue ?

Comment: @Whisher your other problem is with MySQL; nothing to do with hapi. You might be better making a new question.