# Does hapijs have something like overload protection?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

What will a hapi server do if it is overloaded and is there something like [toobusy-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/toobusy-js) to prevent a fallout of the server by shortcutting some requests with errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's embedded in the framework, look at `load` on connections [settings](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#new-serveroptions).
You have 3 options :

- `maxHeapUsedBytes` - maximum V8 heap size over which incoming requests are rejected with an HTTP Server Timeout (503) response. Defaults to 0 (no limit).
- `maxRssBytes` - maximum process RSS size over which incoming requests are rejected with an HTTP Server Timeout (503) response. Defaults to 0 (no limit).
- `maxEventLoopDelay` - maximum event loop delay duration in milliseconds over which incoming requests are rejected with an HTTP Server Timeout (503) response. Defaults to 0 (no limit).
  `

And you must not forget to set a sample interval (time between 2 checks) on `server.load` config:

- `sampleInterval` - the frequency of sampling in milliseconds. Defaults to 0 (no sampling).

Example :

server configuration :

```
{
  "load": {
    "sampleInterval": 1000
  }
}
```

connection configuration :

```
{
  "load": {
    "maxHeapUsedBytes": 1073741824,
    "maxRssBytes": 1610612736,
    "maxEventLoopDelay": 5000
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but what's the reasonable values for the options ?

Comment: The reason is to prevent a complete fallout of the server (see the question above). I better reject some users in the web service and work for others instead of the server goes into a heavy load and becomes unmanagable.

Comment: @Pierre Inglebert the options works in dev env but doesn't work in test env with lab

Comment: @Pierre Inglebert when I run npm test I got this (take a look at https://gist.github.com/whisher/3a6b1d0abe14057a5ba8)

Comment: Have you start the server ? Check this test for example : https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/cf267f91eb179555956fd7081cd86444a53dd8c6/test/server.js#L260
I dont set load conf in my tests.

Comment: Yes without your option it works I'm using Lab take a look at this post there is a suite test http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807290/hapi-lab-how-do-i-have-shared-state-between-lab-experiments

Comment: If you add these options, you must call `server.start` before testing your routes. Btw, it's useless to set it for tests unless you want to test this behavior.

Comment: Yes you right just get rid of the options in the configuration file it's just to point it out.